# irc: message notification when away (xchat)

Tags: irc, xchat

We are using IRC in my office for internal communication. It is very impractical to disconnect/reconnect every time I leave/return to my office. Therefore I leave my irc client (`xchat`) running all the time.

But lets say, I got stuck in a meeting, and I have my laptop with me. Is there a way to check whether somebody has sent me any message ? I know, that I cannot connect from second machine under the same account.

Or perhaps would it be possible to forward a copy of every `irc` message on my `jabber` (which I can then check on my laptop) ?

I would not mind, if I got all messages on my `jabber`, regardless whether I am away from my office or not.

I hope my question is not too vague. I don't know where to start looking. I would appreciate any comment/suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [znc](http://wiki.znc.in/ZNC), which is what I use. It's an IRC bouncer which connects to your IRC network on your behalf, and you connect to the IRC bouncer. It looks something like this:

> Your laptop <====> ZNC (hosted on some server) <====> IRC Network

As soon as you get disconnected ZNC will mark you away and log your messages. Once you log back in, it marks you un-away and you receive all your messages sent to you while you were offline. However, you'll need to install it on a server which is always on. If your IRC network resides on your internal network only, then you'll need to install it on your server which also is on the internal network.

If your IRC server is reachabe on public IP, you can use one of the hosted IRC bouncers like [IRCRelay](https://www.ircrelay.com/).